# Attach $watch to input field in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive

The directive below is intended to take the value of the `<input>` tag and render the exact number of boxes. This directive needs to be restricted to `E` (bad design but is what it is), so it looks like I need to find some way of attaching a `$watch` to the input field.

Below you can see my best attempt, or at least a general sketch of what I'd like to accomplish, however this only triggers when the page originally loads. No change to the value in the input box is reflected by the `alert` statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<draw-boxes count="3"></draw-boxes>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("drawBoxes", function() {
    var input = "<input type='text'></input>";
    var htmlCanvas = "<canvas width='800' height='800'></canvas>";
    var template = input + htmlCanvas;
    var linker = function(scope, el, attrs){
        scope.$watch(el.children()[0], function (v) {
                alert('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
                //Will do some canvas drawing here based on input
            });

    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template : template,
        link: linker
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `ng-model` within your directive's input field?

Comment: @JanS That seems easiest but I can't seem to find a method that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-change` on the input. Here is an example:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("drawBoxes", function() {
    var linker = function(scope, el, attrs){
        scope.valueChanged = '';
        scope.change = function() {
           scope.valueChanged = 'new value is ' + scope.value;
        };
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template : "<input type='text' ng-change=\"change()\" ng-model=\"value\"></input>"+
        "<span>{{valueChanged}}</span>" +
        "<canvas width='800' height='800'></canvas>",
        link: linker
    };
```

Here is a working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9ryypze/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would try attaching a controller to the directive.

Also, the input field will need to have a unique ng-model value attached to it.

Then your $scope.$watch can check if the value has changed for the input field whenever any $scope value changes.

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<draw-boxes count="3"></draw-boxes>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("drawBoxes", function() {
    var input = "<input type='text' ng-model='watchedInput'></input>";
    var htmlCanvas = "<canvas width='800' height='800'></canvas>";
    var template = input + htmlCanvas;

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template : template,
        controller: function($scope) {
              $scope.$watch(function() {
                  // when a $scope value is changed, return the 
                  // value you want this watcher to watch
                  return $scope.watchedInput;  
              }, function(newValue) {
                  // if the value returned above is different from the
                  // previous value, this function will be invoked
                  // passing in the changed value as newValue
                  alert('value changed, new value is: ' + newValue);
              }, true);
        },
        scope: {},
        bindToController: true
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

FYI: I haven't tested this code but wanted to illustrate the idea.

Comment: This looks like the best approach. How would I pass the new value to the directive's `link` function?

Comment: You could try the same approach using ng-model and the modified scope.$watch to see if the watcher functions will start firing correctly within a link function rather than a controller.

Or you could try the controller approach and inject $element as a controller dependency to try to reference the directive's element